# rsyncing files only if they exist in target

Tags: rsync

I'd like to know how I can sync only existing files and directories in the target directory.

For example, if I have in the source:

```
a\
b\
b.txt
a.txt
```

... and in the target:

```
a\
a.txt
```

Then I would like rsync to update `a\` (including all files in it, on the source) and `a.txt` but ignore copying `b\` and `b.txt`.

Answer (score 11):

Type in `man rsync` into the terminal to see the man page. It shows you all the options available and explains them. I think what you are looking for is

```
--existing              skip creating new files on receiver
```

so use it as option

```
rsync --existing
```

Comment: This does not help me. Because I do want files in the folder `a\` in the above example to be created recursively. I just want to skip any files and folders being created on level 1.

Comment: I think this is easy to miss when reading your question. Maybe you could make that detail stand out a little more.